# SMTPJS script doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, smtp, email

I am tired of writing php scripts so I am trying to work with [www.smtpjs.com](http://www.smtpjs.com).

I included the script in the index.html:

```
<script src="js/smtp.js"></script>
```

and this is my js code:

```
Email.send("contact@maky.biz", //from
           data.email, //to
           "Demande de devis depuis bla.com",
           "avec smtp.gmail.com", 
           "smtp.gmail.com",
           "me@gmail.com",
           "mypass");
```

Should I configure something more to make this work?

Comment: ok, I just edited the title

Comment: Include errors from js console, if you have any there.

Comment: Hi @NikolayFominyh, I have no errors in the console !

Comment: I have the same problem as the author

Comment: Too bad this script doesn't seem to work, the promise was teasing !

Comment: why dose not work ?

Comment: [See the answer from another feed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42147284/1448871)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it might be useful for future readers...

smtp.google.com listens on port 465 but the default configuration of the smtp.js service is over port 25. You might want to try to encrypt the SMTP settings in a security token as mentioned on the smtp.js homepage :

> By default, the SMTP connection is secure (STARTTLS) and over port 25. If you need to use an SMTP server that does not accepts secure connections, or in on a non-standart port, like 587, then use the button above "Encrypt your SMTP Credentials" to store advanced configuration.