# Using SmtpJS in a userscript: Doesn't work, no error messages?

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts, smtpjs

I'm trying to send an email through a userscript using smtpjs because it seems the easiest approach. However it seems more difficult than just sending it by javascript that is embedded in a HTML page. Using this userscript ([based on the smtpjs website](http://www.smtpjs.com/)) I get no error in the console and no email is sent, is this a framework issue or am I missing something here? (if you suggest an easier way to send emails within a userscript don't hesitate to share)

```
 // ==UserScript==
    // @name         New Userscript
    // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
    // @version      0.1
    // @description  try to take over the world!
    // @author       You
    // @match        *
    // @grant        none
    // @require      http://smtpjs.com/smtp.js
    // ==/UserScript==

    if (confirm("send mail?")) {
        Email.send("FROM@gmail.com",
                   "TO@gmail.com",
                   "This is a subject",
                   "this is the body",
                   "smtp.gmail.com",
                   "USER",
                   "PW");
    }
```

(I tried gmailAPI (pure JS version doesn't support sending emails?) and emailjs framework without success in userscripts)

Comment: please leave a vote or contribute if you find useful information in the answer/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [smtpjs.com source](http://smtpjs.com/smtp.js), it creates a post request url, then appends it to the document inside of a `<link>`. This won't work on secure pages.

```
/* SmtpJS.com */
Email = {
  send: function (t, e, o, n, d, r, c) {
    var a = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1),
     m = "http://smtpjs.com/smtp.aspx?";
     m += "From=" + t,
     m += "&to=" + e,
     m += "&Subject=" + encodeURIComponent(o),
     m += "&Body=" + encodeURIComponent(n),
     void 0 == d.token ?
       (m += "&Host=" + d, m += "&Username=" + r, m += "&Password=" + c, m += "&Action=Send") :
       (m += "&SecureToken=" + d.token, m += "&Action=SendFromStored"),
     m += "&cachebuster=" + a,
     Email.addScript(m) 
  },
  addScript: function (t) {
    var e = document.createElement("link");
    e.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"),
    e.setAttribute("type", "text/xml"),
    e.setAttribute("href", t),
    document.body.appendChild(e)
  }
};
```

You could use most of the above code... keep the `send` function, but replace the `addScript` function with a [`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#POST_request) to post the data to their server.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Seems the [newer version](https://smtpjs.com/smtp.js) of smtpjs uses `XMLHttpRequest` to an HTTPS endpoint. However, it still doesn't seem to work for me.